# how to get number of read bytes

Tags: c, numbers, stdin, fread

when I read from stdin like this:

```
size_t bufSize = 1024;
unsigned char inputBuffer[bufSize];
size_t readNum = 0;
readNum = fread(inputBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char) * bufSize, 1, stdin);
```

in the readNum are stored number of object, this mean when I read from stdin 1024 bytes, the readNum has value 1. But when I read from stdin < 1024 bytes, than readNum has value 0. Question is, how can I recognize how many bytes was read from stdin when the number is less then 1024?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `readNum = fread(inputBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), bufSize, stdin);`

You're trying to read `bufSize` elements, each with a size `sizeof(char)` - not one element with a size of `bufSize * sizeof(char)` - so your `fread` call should reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

fread reads blocks with the given size and returns the number of sucessfully read blocks.
If you want to return the number of bytes read then set the blocksize to 1 and the number of blocks to the number of bytes you want to read:

```
readNum = fread(inputBuffer, 1, sizeof(unsigned char) * bufSize, stdin);
```

Comment: This is inefficient read from stdin after one byte, I created the dynamic array, where I store values from inputBuffer and realloc the dynamic array in cycle, when I read from stdin with 1 byte bufSize, the performance is cca 12 MB/s. But when I have size of bufSize 256 K bytes, the read performance is 509 MB/s. So my idea was, have this 256KB buffer and when readNum is 0, than from inputBuffer store only read bytes, but how?

Answer (score 0):

```
readNum = fread(inputBuffer, 1, sizeof(unsigned char)*bufSize, stdin);
```